# Is there a way to stop the running instance of firebase cloud function -- It has gone into an infinite loop

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which has some code like this:

```
exports.functionName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    //some logic
    b().then(function(otherData){
       //further logic
       resolve(otherDataModified)
    });
});

b = () => {
    if(someError){
      b();
      resolve(); //This is where i made the mistake, this should be returned after b has completed
    }else{
      resolve();
    }
}
```

Now the thing is that I had already called this function twice before realizing the mistake and that has led to the function b going into infinite loop and although the request has completed and resolved and I showed the error to user, there are two functions that are running constantly into background and I see no options to actually stop the execution of this.

Also tried updating the function with correct logic and the new runs are all working correctly but this run is totally hanged up and if not checked can cause me a lot of resource billing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should delete the Cloud Function by going to the Google Cloud console (not the Firebase one) at:

https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

You will see a table which lists your deployed Cloud Functions: at the end of each line you find a three dots button. Click on this button and choose "Delete".

Comment: Thanks, did'nt realize it was that easy!

Comment: It doesn’t keep running in the background?

Comment: @JohnAndrews AFAIK it will kill it and stop the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

As of september 2022, the three dots with the choice to delete the cloud function can be seen on the Firebase Console.

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME/functions

I would like to be sure that deleting the function will abort its execution while testing, because infinite loops will become very expensive surprises.